# Auto suggest in editable field

Tags: javascript, php

I don't know if it is a stupid Q. I have a code which give me auto suggestion. Code is

HTML

```
<textarea cols="50" type="text" name="dealer_details" value="" id="country" onkeyup="suggest(this.value);"  onblur="fill();" class="" required autofocus style="border:none;resize: none;font-size:20px;width:80%;height:20px;"></textarea>
<div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;"> 
<div class="suggestionList" id="suggestionsList"> &nbsp; </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
<script>
function suggest(inputString,depo){
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
    }
    else{
        $('#country').addClass('load');
        $('#depo').addClass('load');
        $.post("autosuggest.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+"",depo: ""+depo+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
                    $('#suggestionsList').html(data);
                    $('#country').removeClass('load');
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function fill(thisValue) {
        $('#country').val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').fadeOut();", 100);
}
</script>
```

autosuggest.php is

```
$queryString = $_POST['queryString'];

if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id as id,company as mm FROM `supplier` WHERE company LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 3");
    if($query != 0) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
            echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result->id.'=>'.$result->mm).'\');">'.$result->id.'==>'.$result->mm.'</li>';

    }
        echo '</ul>';

    }

    }
}
```

It's working good but I need to use a link form where i click add for salary it increase field.
    Add for sallary

Their in salary_name field i need the auto suggest value, code are

```
  <input class="control-label" id="focusedInput" type="text" name="salary_name[]">

<input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" type="text" name="salary[]">
```

AND js are

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#addform").click(function(){

$("#new_input").after('<div class="control-group"><input class="control-label" id="focusedInput" type="text" name="sallary_name[]" placeholder="Employee Name"><div class="controls"> <input class="input-xlarge focused" name="sallary[]" type="text" placeholder="Sallary_amount"></input></div></div>');

$("#hiderow").hide();
$("#hiderow").show(); });   });
```

As i am new in this site and not good enough in js. So please any suggestion would be helpful. 
Thanks in advance.